# How does Entity Framework 6 handle complex null objects?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a complex object, in a Code First Entity Framework 6 project class, like this:

```
public class myobject
{
  [Key]
  public int? id { get; set; } = null;
  public reason myreason { get; set; } // = new reason(); (1)
}
// [NotMapped] (2)
public class reason
{
  // [Key] (3)
  // public int? id { get; set; } = null; (3)
  public string reason { get; set; }
  public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the following Context:

```
public class context : DbContext
{
  public context() : base("name=DataModel")
  {

  }
  public virtual DbSet<myobject> myObjectDb { get; set; }
  // public virtual DbSet<reason> myReasonDb { get; set; } (3)
}
```

So when it's setup like this, I get a DB table that looks like this:

```
TABLE: myobject
INT (PRIMARY KEY): id
NVARCHAR(MAX): reason_reason (nullable)
NVARCHAR(MAX): reason_value (nullable)
```

However, when I attempt to write data to the DB, like this:

```
var obj = new myobject();

using (var db = new context())
{
  // myobject.myreason = new reason(); (4)
  db.myobject.Add(obj);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'reason'.'
UpdateException: Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'reason'.
```

So I have done a ton of poking around and I understand that you can't have null complex types in EF. I'm not entirely clear if that's something that has gone away in EF6 or just older versions. Mainly, I'm confused b/c if null values weren't allowed, why would EF create the fields in the DB and make them nullable? That seems strange.

Anyways, if I un-comment my comment (1) above, which is ordinarily how I would handle this, I still get the same problem. I would think this would make sure that in the event `reason` was null, it would at least have a default object, albeit with null values, but probably not a big deal b/c they are strings.

So I also found if I un-comment my comment (2) above instead, this actually causes the two fields to be removed from the DB entirely (as expected, `NotMapped`). I no longer get an error, but I don't get the data either.

Next I tried un-commenting the comments labeled (3) instead, now I get my two values back, but they are instead in a new table entirely. Again, this makes sense, and the code will run. But, what I'm looking for is the flattened format from the first version, just the ability to handle the `null` object.

So then I went back, and instead of that one, I just added the `new reason();` after I instantiated, like comment (4) above. This in fact works, with the 2 fields in the DB as setup initially. So this works.

I guess my question is why (1) DOES NOT work, but (4) DOES work? They seem like they should accomplish the same thing, albeit if I do (4) then I have to do this after every time I instantiate, and also, I have to check each value if it's null first, b/c if it already has data, I will overwrite.

Also, this is a simple example and only a single object, I have a more complex situation with hundreds.

Any help would be great! I'm completely lost.

I'm hoping this is a really simple fix and I'm missing some glaringly silly mistake.

Comment: I didnt even know that complex types were a thing in EF. What happens if you instantiate the object in the `myobject` constructor? Also, just to make sure (although it should't be much of a difference), the line marked with (4) should be `obj.myreason = new reason();` instead?

Comment: Primary keys can never be null.  Think about it.

Comment: If you are referring to the PK above apparently the value in code is irrelevant if it's a Key. When it writes to the DB it assigns an auto number identity value. Also the constructor instantiation is (1) above. And sorry yes (4) is as you state.  I mistyped.

Comment: Sorry I've been away for a while. Did you solve it? About (1), I was asking specifically to instantiate in the constructor itself, not in the property. It ~should~ be the same thing, and it should not solve the problem... but is it true? It's just my curiosity.